# Gherkin/ Cucumber - How to reference from a cell in a datatable to a row in an another datatable

Tags: cucumber, gherkin, cucumber-java

I want to use Cucumber to test my REST API. 
Therefore I would like to fill the database with a few test data and send a GET request in the When Step. It would be great, if I could explain the state of the database within the steps. So is it possible to reference from a cell in a datatable to a row in an other? Something like this:

```
Given the system knows of the following products
  | productId   | productName   | productCategory |
  | 1           | Kaffee        | {{HotDrinks}}   |
  | 2           | Espresso      | {{HotDrink}}    |
  | 3           | Hot Chocolate | {{KidsDrinks}}  |
And the system knows about the following productCategories
  |                 | productCategoryId | productCategoryName  | customizations  |
  | {{HotDrinks}}   | 1                 | HotDrinks            | "milk", "shots" |
  | {{KidsDrinks}}  | 2                 | KidsDrinks           | "cream"         |
And the system knows about the following customizations
  |               | customizationId | customizationName | kinds             |
  | {{milk}}      | 1               | milk              | skim, semi, whole |
  | {{shots}}     | 2               | shots             | single, double    |
  | {{cream}}     | 3               | cream             | true              |
When a client requests GET /productCatalogue
Then the HTTP response status will be 200
And the response body contains the following JSON
"""
...
"""
```

Is there any way to do something like this?

Answer (score -1):

You can use [NoraUi](http://noraui.github.io) (NoraUi, for NOn-Regression Automation for User Interfaces, is a Java framework based on Selenium, Cucumber and Gherkin stack to create GUI testing projects that can be included in the continuous integration chain of single/multi applications web solution builds.)

if you do not use this complete and turnkey framework, you can take inspiration from their code. There is a complete example in the contuned integration of this framework. In the scenarios "[hello](https://github.com/NoraUi/NoraUi/blob/master/src/test/resources/steps/hello.feature)" you find the following step:

```
And I save the value of REST API 'GET' 'GITHUBAPI_HOME' '/search/users?q=location:rennes+language:java&page=1&per_page=10' in 'title' context key.
```

This step match whith this Java code (full code [here](https://github.com/NoraUi/NoraUi/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/noraui/application/steps/RESTSteps.java)):

```
@And("I save the value of REST API '(.*)' '(.*)' '(.*)' in '(.*)' context key[\\.|\\?]")
public void saveValue(String method, String pageKey, String uri, String targetKey, List<GherkinStepCondition> conditions) throws TechnicalException, FailureException {
    ...
    try {
        json = httpService.get(Context.getUrlByPagekey(pageKey), uri);
    } catch (HttpServiceException e) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

HttpService code [here](https://github.com/NoraUi/NoraUi/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/noraui/service/impl/HttpServiceImpl.java). This service use `okhttp3.OkHttpClient`

Comment: a person has downvote but surely by mistake because this solution is currently working in production. In addition, this person did not propose a better solution.